# What is the correct term to describe 'primary', 'secondary', etc

Tags: single-word-requests, numbers, hypernyms

What is the correct term to describe the words in the following sequence: *primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, quinary, senary, septenary, octonary, nonary, denary, duodenary*, etc.

I am thinking '-tier' but I don't think I am correct.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I believe the words you have there are Latinate [ordinal numbers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordinal+number?show=0&t=1354142701).

Comment: This answer I think is the more complete one because it is necessary to call them Latinate to differentiate from *first*, *second,* etc., (even though *second* is of latinate origin...)

Comment: Their role English probably must be special, distinct from the normal ordinal numbers. Just calling them "Latinate" wouldn't explain this special role. Compare to Russian: the translation of these English Latinate ordinal numbers into Russian are words different than the normal Russian ordinals, but formed from the same Russian roots for ordinals: первый (first) vs первичный (primary), второй vs вторичный, etc. There might be a more universal description of the role these words play in a language.

Answer (score 11):

From Wikipedia's 
[Ordinal number (linguistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number_%28linguistics%29) article:

> In linguistics, **ordinal numbers** are the words representing the rank of a number with respect to some order, in particular order or position (i.e. first, second, third, etc.). Its use may refer to size, importance, chronology, etc. ...
>   They are different from the cardinal numbers (one, two, three, etc.) referring to the quantity.
>   Ordinal numbers are alternatively written in English with numerals and letter suffixes: 1st, 2nd or 2d, 3rd or 3d, 4th, 11th, 21st, 101st, 477th, etc. ...
>   Spatial or chronological ranks will use the standard linguistic ordinal numbers first, second, etc.; however, the ranking of precedence or effect often uses primary, secondary, etc.[2] and historical rankings in literature, biology or music may use Greek prefixes, e.g., Proto-Isaiah, Deutero-Isaiah ...